# Where did my bounty go?

Tags: support, bounty

I asked a question, to which I only received somewhat negative comments which questioned my reasoning (and seemingly my sanity for even asking such a question).

I felt it was still a valid question, as it definitely relates to electronics, so I offered a bounty. The bounty expired several days ago and there are still no answers. My bounty has been subtracted from my rep but has not been returned.

I can't seem to find any information about this particular case in the FAQ.

Will I ever get my bounty back?

Comment: No, it's gone. A bounty is a incentive to go a bit above and beyond, but most people will still want to feel the question is worthwhile and the answer will be useful. I saw your bounty, but it failed on both accounts for me.

Comment: I thought bounty was also to offer incentive to just answer the bloody question ;)

Comment: Exactly, it's a incentive.  That doesn't mean anyone is forced to take it or that the incentive is enough to make them want to bother answering the question.  You asked a question that apparently nobody felt they could answer or felt worth answering, even with the bounty.  You did get a bunch of advice, but your refusal to accept any of it probably turned most people off.  I know it did for me.

Comment: @glenneroo, It was an honestly question which seems to have had the community want you to learn something more productive. I dont know why everyone decided you should stop what you are doing and move on, but sometimes we are quite pompous in the EE realm. I have attached a larger bounty and we will see if anyone just answers it. Sorry that no one gave you a decent answer, for some reason you just amassed a large number of nonconstructive comments. Feel free to come to chat if you want to discuss issues like this or flag a moderator if you think something is going awry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty).

> In any case, you will *always* give up the amount of reputation
>   specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow
>   up and award your bounty to the best answer!

Comment: This seems a bit unfair IMO. Only 7 days for someone to answer and if nobody answers, then it disappears permanently? I wish I understood the mentality behind this decision.

Comment: @glenneroo 7 days here may be different than in SO which is more crowded; though, I'm quite sure that all the most knowledgeable members of the site have read your question, and if they didn't answer is probably because they didn't feel like answering, for whatever reason

Comment: @glenneroo, none of the experienced guys wanted to admit it would take them research to find out how to do what you were asking. a little rep was not enough to get them going, A bit more seems to get he job done.